# How to use regexp to find first occurance of letters and the subsequent numbers in a string?

Tags: python, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have different products, there are 4 different ways they can be presented.

1. 1/ABC123456
2. ABC123456
3. ABC123456/1
4. 1/ABC123456/1

In all of these cases I want to extract "ABC" and "123" from the product name. 
I know that I should be able to use reg exp for this, but I am not sure how to construct the pattern.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please add realistic input strings.

Comment: What is the rule that makes you extract `123`? Why not `123456`? Do you mean 'all letters and the next 3 digits'? You should clarify that.

Comment: These are actual realistic input strings. First 3 letters are prod category, e.g ABC. Then it is product type which is the following 3 numbers. I do not need the following numbers since they relate to other info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for a group of 3 letters followed by 3 digits:

import re

```
tests = ["1/ABC123456", "ABC123456", "ABC123456/1", "1/ABC123456/1"]

for ref in tests:
    print(re.search(r'[A-Za-z]{3}\d{3}', ref).group(0))
```

Output:

```
ABC123
ABC123
ABC123
ABC123
```

[search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search) looks for the first location where the pattern matches, so you don't have to care about the `1/` that could appear at the start of your reference.